# Track optimisation over waypoints radius

Tags: javascript, google-maps, gps, geometry

I can't seem to solve the following problem :

Using Google map (and WSG84) I have a set of waypoints defining an air/sea route. (There is no roads : Just straight lines !). I can draw and estimate a route length easily because I have the coordinates of all waypoints but I'm trying to take into account any existing radius around each waypoints to optimize the fastest available route and get the shortest distance. A picture may illustrate this better.

[image: Route optimisation]
<sub>(source: [ffvl.fr](http://geolocalisation.ffvl.fr/stack.jpg))</sub>

The blue line is easy to sort out. How can I get all intermediates points belonging to each waypoint's radius on the red line ?

Comment: I guess I need to go my way trought the bisectrix of the angle defined by the first segment entering the turnpoint and the second segment exiting the turnpoint (blue line) ? But it's just empirical thought. Would be happy to have a confirmation.

Comment: Turns out Google Map API V3 should provide all I need to implement the approach described above without much hassle : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=FR#spherical Basicaly getting a bearing for each turnpoint with `computeHeading()` and then just using `computeOffset()` from the center of the turnpoint to reach its own radius on the right bearing should work. Will post it once I find enough time to code it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, Téo Bouvard's solution described [Here](https://teobouvard.github.io/2019/10/20/task_optimization.html) with quasi Newtons methods was what I was looking for for such a long time.

His question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58300162/shortest-path-through-ordered-circular-waypoints) look similar than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Google Map API V3 provided all I needed out of the box to implement the bisectrix approach described above : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=FR#spherical

It was  quite easy to implement. The trick was indeed to play with headings and offsets to reach every bisectrix points. A full working exemple can be found at : 
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ce32901c1850f5aaea8b